# Can you override the global ExceptionHandler used by MVC in MVC5 / OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

In WebAPI running on OWIN, you can do this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
```

This allows you to do custom handling in code of all errors which get thrown, even if they are thrown by a controller constructor or during routing.

In MVC you can add a global exception filter, but it only works for errors thrown once the code has gotten into a controller action.

Is there an equivalent of the above for global MVC error handling?

Comment: Have you got an anwser for this?